# My python code uses pywin32 and it failes to run every time

Tags: python, api, pywin32

I am trying to create an api for autodesk inventor and the code I am makeing is always missing some module even though they are there. Does pywin32 no work with python3.10 which I am using. Here is a copy of my latest code:

```py
import win32com.client

def open_inventor_file(file_path):
    try:
        # Get the active instance of the Inventor application
        inventorApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Inventor.Application")

        # Make the application visible
        inventorApp.Visible = True

        # Get the Documents collection
        documents = inventorApp.Documents

        # Open the specified file
        doc = documents.Open(file_path)

        # Start a sketch on the first work plane
        part = doc.ComponentDefinition
        work_plane = part.WorkPlanes[1]
        sketch = part.Sketches.Add(work_plane)
        sketch.Edit()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error opening Autodesk Inventor file:", str(e))

# Specify the file path of the Inventor file you want to open
file_path = r"N:\MISC\Part37.ipt"

# Call the function to open the specified file in Inventor
open_inventor_file(file_path)
```

Help creating the api or with pywin32

This is one of the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Users\Douglas\VISUAL STUDIO\Inventor Holes\Inventor Holes\Inventor_Holes.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "N:\Users\Douglas\VISUAL STUDIO\Inventor Holes\Inventor Holes\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): if you get errors, please [edit] your post to show those errors (in text form, with code formatting), and remember to talk about all the things you already did, search/found, etc, in order to solve your problem, so that people know what not to suggest because you already tried that.

Comment: Can you also explain how you're running this code in your post?

Comment: Those paths look strange to me. How did you install *Python*? What about *PyWin32*?